# How to dynamically create a ngInclude directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I put this in my HTML, it works fine:

```
<div ng-include="'my-template.html'"></div>
```

But when I'm trying to create that ngInclude directive dynamically using jQuery (after the DOM is ready), it does not work:

```
$(function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.setAttribute('ng-include', "'my-template.html'");
  $('.container').replaceWith(el);
});
```

The element is indeed inserted into the DOM with the expected template, but it's not being interpreted as AngularJS code. No errors in console.

What am I missing?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't mix Angular and jQuery. It is a bad approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) your HTML

I'm not sure what the syntax is like in your file (whether you're using requireJS or not) but it should be something similar to compiling the new element with the scope.

```
angular.element('[ng-app]')
       .injector()
       .invoke(['$compile', function ($compile) {
                    var $scope = angular.element(el).scope();
                    $compile(el)($scope);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }]);
```

Comment: Ah, it makes sense. However, now after the compilation, I see this in the HTML: `<!-- ngInclude: 'my-template.html' -->` and naturally, nothing is shown. I'm not using requireJS.

Comment: With `$scope.$apply()` it now works as expected. Maybe you should add it to your answer?

Comment: @MartinCarel Thanks for the feedback, I just added it